# react-native-webview not support mathemetical tags in Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

Below html tag not showing properly in android but in iOS its work fine.

```
"<p><math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\"><mn>6</mn><msqrt><mn>79</mn></msqrt><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>+</mo><msup><mn>88</mn><mn>87</mn></msup><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>=</mo><mo>?</mo></math></p>\r\n\r\n<p>Testing</p>\r\n"
```

My Source Code:

```
const htmlText = "<p><math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\"><mn>6</mn><msqrt><mn>79</mn></msqrt><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>+</mo><msup><mn>88</mn><mn>87</mn></msup><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>=</mo><mo>?</mo></math></p>\r\n\r\n<p>Testing</p>\r\n"

      <WebView
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
          }}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          scalesPageToFit={true}
          source={html: htmlText}
          viewportContent={"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"}
      />
```

Expected Result :
[image]